# How to Check MSDB for User Permissions/Roles

Tags: sql-server, sp-send-dbmail

I have a connectionstring

```
 <add name="DBCon" connectionString="Data Source=10.197.10.10,46512\Games;Initial Catalog=Games;User Id=UserA;Password=;" providerName="SqlMembershipProvider" />
```

Before using sp_send_dbmail and through a sql query, how to check if UserA has any permissions or roles in the msdb database?

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to know if `UserA` is authorized to execute `sp_send_dbmail`.  Is that the question?

Comment: @DMason, that is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's important to understand the difference between a SQL Server `login` (instance level object) and a database `user` (database level object).  In your connection string, the login is named `UserA`, which might be confusing.  "Logins" don't have permissions within a database.  Well, not *directly*.  It's the "user" that the login is mapped to that has permissions.  Ok, enough of that...

**SQL Login**

If your `login` has `sysadmin` role membership, you'll have free reign to do anything, including sending mail via `sp_send_dbmail`.  This query will tell you if the login you're connected as has that membership (look for a return value of "1"):

```
SELECT IS_SRVROLEMEMBER('sysadmin', SUSER_NAME())
```

**Database User - Role Membership**

However, I suspect you're wanting to know if your `login` has a `user` in `msdb`, and if so, does **it** have permission to send mail via `sp_send_dbmail`.   Run this query to see what user in `msdb` (if any) that your login is mapped to and any database roles that user belongs to:

```
SELECT l.name LoginName, u.name UserName, r.name RoleName
FROM master.sys.server_principals l
JOIN msdb.sys.database_principals u
    ON u.sid = l.sid
LEFT JOIN msdb.sys.database_role_members rm
    ON rm.member_principal_id = u.principal_id
LEFT JOIN msdb.sys.database_principals r
    ON r.principal_id = rm.role_principal_id
WHERE l.name = SUSER_NAME()
AND r.name IN ('db_owner', 'DatabaseMailUser')
```

If the user is a member of either `db_owner` or `DatabaseMailUser`, it *should* be able to execute `sp_send_dbmail`.  (If there was an explicit `DENY EXECUTE ON sp_send_dbmail TO [yourDBuser]`, then the user would not have that privilege.)

If the user is `dbo`, then it owns `msdb` (not likely--system databases are typically owned by the `sa` login), and as the database owner, it can perform just about any activity on the db.

**Database User--Individual Grants**

Lastly, there is one other possibility I can think of:  the database user in msdb might not be in any database roles, but could explicitly have been given the privilege to execute `sp_send_dbmail` as follows:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON sp_send_dbmail TO [yourDBuser]
```

This will show you what permissions have been explicitly GRANTED or DENIED to your database user:

```
USE msdb
GO

SELECT * FROM fn_my_permissions(NULL, 'DATABASE');
GO
```

Comment: Maybe I should have called the User Id, UserIdA. Your excellent explanation begs the question, how to find the "user" that the login (in connection string) is mapped to in order to find what permissions this implicit user might or might not have? I access sql server using Windows Authentication, but the application only knows the connection string.

Comment: @usefulBee, it's that query under the **Database User - Role Membership** heading.  Try commenting out the last line (`AND r.name IN...`) and re-run the query.  If there is a db user mapped to your login, you will get back at least one row.  If there is no db user mapped to the login, no rows will be returned.

Comment: Yes, however, I had to comment the first condition as well in order to get any result. I saw a few and 'sa' is one of them, but not any that matches my logins. Your insight is highly appreciated!

Comment: `WHERE l.name = SUSER_NAME()`....yeah this certainly adds to the confusion.  The built-in function `SUSER_NAME()` returns the name of a SQL login, not a database user. (Kinda misleading function name, right?)   If you run `SELECT SUSER_NAME()` by itself, it should return your SQL login name (doesn't matter if it's SQL authentication or Windows authentication).  I used it in my example so the query would only return info for your login.  HTH

Comment: SELECT SUSER_NAME() that was very useful!